# scan a page via WIA in vc++ got an error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wia

I saw this way of coding in Microsoft " WIA tutorial " page but the vc++ doesn't let me to compile it! some errors appear all the time!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Strsafe.h>
#include <Wia.h>
#include <WinError.h>

bool CreateWiaDeviceManager( IWiaDevMgr2 **ppWiaDevMgr ){
//
// Validate arguments
//
if (NULL == ppWiaDevMgr)
{
    return E_INVALIDARG;
}
//
// Initialize out variables
//
*ppWiaDevMgr = NULL;

//
// Create an instance of the device manager
//


//Vista or later:
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WiaDevMgr2, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWiaDevMgr2, (void**)ppWiaDevMgr ); 

//
// Return the result of creating the device manager
//
return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}
```

There are errors:

1>WIAScanner.cpp(11): error C2065: 'IWiaDevMgr2' : undeclared identifier
1>WIAScanner.cpp(11): error C2065: 'ppWiaDevMgr' : undeclared identifier
1>WIAScanner.cpp(11): error C2448: 'CreateWiaDeviceManager' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IWiaDevMgr2` is only available in Windows Vista or later, so you need to target your project appropriately: [`_WIN32_WINNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt) needs to be defined as `0x0600` or greater.

Comment: You need to do it right, it will work. You have to define `_WIN32_WINNT` early enough, via project settings or via `stdafx.h` depending on your project layout.

Comment: After I set '_WIN32_WINNT_' to 0x0600 via project setting I have got too many errors like : '    __out_z LPSTR lpString1, // deprecated: annotation is as good as it gets'    or '1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winbase.h(6141): error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'LPWSTR''

Comment: Hint: you can create a new project which typically has the necessary definitions (explicitly, or through inclusion of `<sdkdefs.h>` etc.) and then copy your code there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what to do. By the way, thanks for ur help @Roman R.